# Heroku CLI not working

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

Back in my office I installed heroku CLI without trouble (Ubuntu 11.04). Now, after installing it in my laptop (Ubuntu 10.04) I'm getting the following error:

```
$ heroku 
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `load'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `load'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:28
```

In both cases I followed the same procedure:

- Install [heroku-toolbelt](http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/linux/readme)
- Install ruby with `sudo apt-get install ruby`
- Install git
- Test heroku CLI: `$ heroku`

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `readline` as the error states.

```
apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Comment: Actually, I solved it by doing `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`. I guess `libreadline-dev` was a dependency of that package. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it was this one that solved it: `libreadline-ruby`. It's available in lucid but not in natty

Answer (score 1):

This is what actually worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-ruby1.9.1
```